# performance lag when composing SVG with multiple jpg images

Tags: svg, svg.js

Background:

I have requirement of showing picture representation of storage hardware(configured from smaller hardware pieces), Using svgjs library to compose storage hardware SVG image from 100-500 smaller pieces of jpg image.

Problem:

Seeing performance lag, page is not responsive for around 30-40 seconds when there is big configuration uses more than 400 smaller images to compose SVG, actually there are only 15 different jpg images are downloaded from server, these images are very small in size, it is around 600 KB and download time is around 3 seconds combining all of the them, but the page is taking 30-40 seconds to be full responsive.

Around 80KB of DOM is generated for this SVG image.
Example of HTML representation of SVG: https://ibb.co/0jYgBBk

The reason i am using SVG instead of canvas is i have some minor interaction with image once loaded, like adding and removing shapes on svg(for example highlighting particular piece of hardware)

Any solution to improve the performance.

Comment: Just to confirm: the last image finishes downloading at the 3sec mark?  And it is responsive after 30-40s?  At what point is it fully rendered?  Is it less than 30s?  Which browser are you testing with?  Is there a difference between them?

Comment: Is it SVG.js at fault perhaps? Have you tried saving one of the final images as a static SVG, then timing how fast it takes to load that?

Comment: Thanks Paul, yes all the images are downloaded at the 3sec mark and page will be responsive after more than 30 secs.. and half image will be rendered at the beginning.. but the remaining half will render at the end.. and I am using only chrome latest.. from your commend i have tried saving image to svg file loading it directly instead of composing from configuration.. image loaded very fast and no lag at all.. this configuration is not directly used.. there are some transformation in between looks like there is some code taking time to execute, looks like no issue with svg.js.. thanks.